# how to split one column to multiple column with header in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data which is in one column. i want to create time series.. so i want to split one column into multiple column with header. this is my data on this link and there are always 168 values. https://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/nybirths.dat

and i want to data like this way :[image]

How to do this.. please help!!

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots or links to either code, data, or output.  Take the time to construct a question which has all the relevant information listed inline, as correctly formatted code and example input/output.  Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create an [mcve], then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create 1d numpy array
url = 'https://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/nybirths.dat'
a = pd.read_csv(url, names=['val']).values

c = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
i = np.arange(1946, 1960)

#reshape and create new DataFrame by contructor
df = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(14, 12), index=i, columns=c)
```

---

```
print (df)

         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep  \
1946  26.663  23.598  26.931  24.740  25.806  24.364  24.477  23.901  23.175   
1947  21.439  21.089  23.709  21.669  21.752  20.761  23.479  23.824  23.105   
1948  21.937  20.035  23.590  21.672  22.222  22.123  23.950  23.504  22.238   
1949  21.548  20.000  22.424  20.615  21.761  22.874  24.104  23.748  23.262   
1950  22.604  20.894  24.677  23.673  25.320  23.583  24.671  24.454  24.122   
1951  23.287  23.049  25.076  24.037  24.430  24.667  26.451  25.618  25.014   
1952  23.798  22.270  24.775  22.646  23.988  24.737  26.276  25.816  25.210   
1953  24.364  22.644  25.565  24.062  25.431  24.635  27.009  26.606  26.268   
1954  24.657  23.304  26.982  26.199  27.210  26.122  26.706  26.878  26.152   
1955  24.990  24.239  26.721  23.475  24.767  26.219  28.361  28.599  27.914   
1956  26.217  24.218  27.914  26.975  28.527  27.139  28.982  28.169  28.056   
1957  26.589  24.848  27.543  26.896  28.878  27.390  28.065  28.141  29.048   
1958  27.132  24.924  28.963  26.589  27.931  28.009  29.229  28.759  28.405   
1959  26.076  25.286  27.660  25.951  26.398  25.565  28.865  30.000  29.261   

         Oct     Nov     Dec  
1946  23.227  21.672  21.870  
1947  23.110  21.759  22.073  
1948  23.142  21.059  21.573  
1949  22.907  21.519  22.025  
1950  24.252  22.084  22.991  
1951  25.110  22.964  23.981  
1952  25.199  23.162  24.707  
1953  26.462  25.246  25.180  
1954  26.379  24.712  25.688  
1955  27.784  25.693  26.881  
1956  29.136  26.291  26.987  
1957  28.484  26.634  27.735  
1958  27.945  25.912  26.619  
1959  29.012  26.992  27.897
```

Comment: one more question.. if i want to convert this df file ti csv.. how to do this?

Comment: Use `df.to_csv('out.csv')`, check [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)